# Trouble with Tkinter entry widget

Tags: python, widget, tkinter

I'm following this intro to tkinter, specifically the dialog entry example on page 29. http://www.ittc.ku.edu/~niehaus/classes/448-s04/448-standard/tkinter-intro.pdf

I'm getting the following error:

```
d = MyDialog(root)
TypeError: this constructor takes no arguments
```

I deleted the argument from the variable d, and the argument for wait_window (see the code below) and the program will run, however there is no entry field.

Here is the code

```
from Tkinter import *

class MyDialog:

    def init(self, parent):

        top = Toplevel(parent)

        Label(top, text="Value").pack()

        self.e = Entry(top)
        self.e.pack(padx=5)

        b = Button(top, text="OK", command=self.ok)
        b.pack(pady=5)

    def ok(self):
        print "value is", self.e.get()

        self.top.destroy()

root = Tk()
Button(root, text="Hello!").pack()
root.update()

d = MyDialog(root)

root.wait_window(d.top)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change

```
def init(self, parent):
```

to

```
def __init__(self, parent):
```

See the documentation of [`object.__init__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__init__).

Comment: Hmmm ... OP isn't actually using `object.__init__` since this is an old style class -- but you're right, it does basically the same thing.

Comment: If you have a new question, post it as a new one. And please don't edit your question to include an answer. Your original question has be answered. Please accept one of these answers.

Comment: @Tichodroma -- Good point.  1 question per post is definitely preferred.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change

```
def init(self, parent):
    ...
```

to

```
def __init__(self, parent):
    ...
```

(Note the bracketing double underscores).

In python, the documentation is a little fuzzy on what it calls the constructor, but `__init__` is often refered to as the constructor (although some will argue that is the job of `__new__`.).  Semantics aside, the arguments passed to `MyClass(arg1,arg2,...)` will get passed to `__init__` (provided you don't do funny things in `__new__` which is a discussion for a different time).  e.g.:

```
class MyFoo(object): #Inherit from object.  It's a good idea
    def __init__(self,foo,bar):
       self.foo = foo
       self.bar = bar

my_instance = MyFoo("foo","bar")
```

As your code is, since you don't define `__init__`, the default is being used which is equivalent to:

```
def __init__(self): pass
```

which takes no arguments (other than the compulsory `self`)

---

You'll also need to do:

```
self.top = Toplevel(...)
```

since later you try to get the top attribute (`d.top`), but `d` has no attribute `top` since you never added as an attribute.